# How do we know that model learned those features from the image dataset in deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, image-classification

I am implementing image classification using TensorFlow.How do we know that model learned those features from the image dataset in deep learning. can we visualize that?

Comment: You can get more details on how to get features from the below links, ideally they used VGG16 model and visualized the feature maps.  https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-visualize-filters-and-feature-maps-in-convolutional-neural-networks/

Comment: Could you please elaborate the questions in a bit more detail